# How to run "clean up permissions" programmatically in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

When I'm changing role programmatically then updated role is not taking place immediately until run *clean up permissions* from control panel.

Is there any way to call some APIs to do the same through program itself?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more for what you want to clean up permissions?

Comment: During the user login wanted to change role in Hook. Role is getting changed but the associated permissions are not updating immediately. After manual run of “clean up permission” from control panel, the changes are reflecting.

Comment: Let me edit and elaborate a little bit more your question.

Answer (score 0):

the method doing it is `CleanUpPermissionsUtil.cleanUpAddToPagePermissions(ActionRequest)` 
but the problem that it is a internal utility and is not possible to call in a plugin. It execute in the PortalContext.

You can see the source of the class at the link and try to replicate the code maybe in your logic 
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/admin/util/CleanUpPermissionsUtil.java

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that you should use to reload permission from update role:

```
Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, RoleConstants.USER);
List<ResourcePermission> roleResourcePermissions = ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getRoleResourcePermissions(role.getRoleId());
for(ResourcePermission permission : roleResourcePermissions )
    ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.reassignPermissions(permission.getResourcePermissionId(),role.getRoleId());
```